# When can RMSEA be zero?

Tags: goodness-of-fit, structural-equation-modeling

If $\text{RMSEA} = 0$, it means $\chi^2 < df$.

Does it disqualify RMSEA as a criterion to evaluate the model fit, or is it just the explanation why it is zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\chi^2_p < p$ is not such an unusual phenomenon: it should be happening about half of the time with perfectly specified models (including the multivariate normality distributional assumptions). RMSEA is a monotone transformation of [non-centrality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution):

$$ {\rm RMSEA} = \sqrt{\max\biggl(\frac T{(N-1)p},0\biggr)}=\sqrt{\hat\lambda/p} $$

where $\hat\lambda$ is the estimated normalized (per observation) non-centrality. I take the latter to be a more fundamental property of an SEM than RMSEA (the latter is prone to weird inconsistencies, see [Chen, Curran, Bollen, Kirby and Paxton (2008), SocMethodRes](http://smr.sagepub.com/content/36/4/462.abstract)). For these perfectly specified models, the population non-centrality is zero, and thus the estimate coincides with the population value in the samples in which chi-square is less than the degrees of freedom (which, if you think of it, is a pretty rare property: when you estimate a mean or a regression coefficient, the probability that the estimate is equal to the population quantity is zero).

BTW, Kris Preacher has a neat RMSEA calculator on this website, see http://www.quantpsy.org/rmsea/rmsea.htm.